# Spring websocket heartbeat Broken pipe IOException

Tags: java, spring, websocket, ioexception, broken-pipe

I'm using spring-boot-starter-websocket with Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE. I get tons of logs when sockjs is trying to perform a heartbeat task. Somehow the connection is lost in the way. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802969/spring-4-websockets-causing-tons-of-exceptions) says its closed (according to [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11438)), but I'm still having the same kind of issue.

Here is my config

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
        
    @Bean
    WebSocketHandler getWsHandler() {
        return new WebSocketHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    } 
}
```

Here are the logs

> 2017-07-11 15:10:23.753  INFO 7574 --- [MessageBroker-4]
> o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : An error occurred in
> processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be
> closed immediately
>
> java.io.IOException: Broken pipe  at
> sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]   at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
> ~[na:1.8.0]   at
> sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0]
> at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0]  at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
> ~[na:1.8.0]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1259)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:581)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:272)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1506)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:279)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]    at
> org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:172)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
> [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
> [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:350)
> [spring-websocket-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:322)
> [spring-websocket-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:255)
> [spring-websocket-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$HeartbeatTask.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java:456)
> [spring-websocket-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
> [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]  at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [na:1.8.0]    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [na:1.8.0]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> [na:1.8.0]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> [na:1.8.0]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [na:1.8.0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0] }

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have exactly the same problem and can't understand how to fix it

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and still can't fix

Comment: For the next one here facing the same problem, please describe what the client-side looks like (browser debugger). Is the websocket connection forcefully closed by the browser?